# How to retrieve the checkbox status from Wordpress post

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following field in Wordpress post:

[image]

I am trying to see what the `var_dump` looks like by this:

```
$get_t = get_field('field1');
var_dump($get_t);
```

If the checkbox in the post hasn't been changed yet, I get the following:

```
bool(false)
```

If the checkbox in the post is checked, I get the following:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" }
```

Then, if the checkbox in the post is unchecked, I get the following:

```
string(0) ""
```

How can I use the `$get_t` to do the following:

```
if (checkbox is not checked) { //bool(false) -OR- string(0) ""
    //do this
}
else { //array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" }
    //do this
}
```

I am doing the following to get the value and the error:

```
$get_t = get_field('field1');
$close_val = "";
if ($get_t != false || count($get_t) !== 0) { //checked
    var_dump($get_t);
    foreach ($get_t as $key => $value) {
        $close_val = $value;
    }
}
else { //unchecked
    // do this
}
```

If checked, it works correctly but if not checked or never modified, I get a warning:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/files.php on line 80
```

Line 80 is the `foreach` line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check first if it's `true` and after check the string

```
if ($get_t == false || count($get_t) === 0) {
    //do this
} else {
    // do this
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if its an array, that means the user has checked the checkbox

```
if (is_array($get_t) && !$get_t){
  // is checked
}
```

Comment: This is almost there, so once the checkbox is checked, it is always an array, even after i uncheck it. It only works if it was never checked to begin with.

Comment: Please check my question for the second two scenarios.

Comment: Updated, try that. So You want to know if its an array(that means is checked) and if its true or no, right? Sorry if I understood in the wrong way @Si8

Comment: Editing and clarifying - +1.

Answer (score 1):

Just change condition form != to ==

```
if ($get_t == false || count($get_t) == 0) {
   //unchecked
}
else {
   //checked       
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I +1 your answer but selected @Iwan as he answered first.